# Cannot create an Azure Application gateway using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to create an instance of Application Gateway. While doing so, I get the following error:

`Error: creating Application Gateway: (Name "name-gateway-wgrkecswbk" / Resource Group "name03n62mct"): network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceName" Message="Resource name  is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must end with a word character or with '_'. The name may contain word characters or '.', '-', '_'." Details=[]`

The name used is `name-gateway-wgrkecswbk` which, looks to be a valid name according the error description.

The location used is

```
   with module.name.module.gateway[0].azurerm_application_gateway.res,
   on .terraform/modules/name/modules/gateway/main.tf line 20, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "name":
   20: resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "name" {
```

Tried removed dashes and making it shorter, with the same results.

Comment: What does the TF look like for defining the "name" parameter of the azurerm_application_gateway resource? Are you sure `name-gateway-wgrkecswbk` is the exact name it's attempting to use for the resource? It's not using string concatenation or other to for the name differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that under `ssl_certificate`, the `name` property was using a variable `ssl_certificate_name` which turned to be `empty`.

Then, the error coming back from `Azure` was half correct; It was an invalid name used, since it was an empty var, but not at the resource level ( `azurerm_application_gateway.name` ), instead it was at the inner block `azurerm_application_gateway.name.ssl_certificate.name` level.

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "name" {

//....

 ssl_certificate {
    // var contents were empty
    name                = var.ssl_certificate_name 
  }

}
```

Already reported this issue to **Azure** so hopefully it gets resolved soon.

Provider version was `3.37`

Answer (score 0):

The **unicode character [i.e., space] on the gateway name** may cause a problem. I have repeated the procedure using the same application gateway name, "**name-gateway-wgrkecswbk**."

below code reference from [harshicop](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_gateway)

main tf as follows:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "**********"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "examples-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.254.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
  name                 = "frontend"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.254.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  name                 = "backend"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.254.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "examples-pip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-rqrt"
  redirect_configuration_name    = "${azurerm_virtual_network.example.name}-rdrcfg"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "name-gateway-wgrkecswbk"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_Small"
    tier     = "Standard"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.frontend.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    path                  = "/path1/"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }
}
```

provide tf as follows:

```
terraform {
  
      required_version = "~>1.3.3"
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
           source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
           version = ">=3.5.0"
             }
           }
 }
```

Output while running plan command

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

upon apply

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

From Portal:
[image]